# Free API or database for Continent, country, city, region/state?

Tags: data, software-recommendations, geolocation

Is there a database or API that can provide: Continent, country, city and region/state? It should also have the country codes in ISO format. It would also be great if if could all be in one file for easy access. Ideally, the API/database shouldn't have too many fields as I would prefer concise data. It would be a good bonus if it included support for different languages.

I found that GeoNames contains too many places and landmarks. Same with Yahoo GeoPlanet. GeoDataSource is too scattered between different files. I prefer something that is not too big and concise and possibly with an hierarchical structure.

---

Actually I found one here!!!!

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/